Word cannot open the document: user does not have access privileges
On Word for Mac, after opening too many documents over a few weeks, the error message Word cannot open the document: user does not have access privileges starts appearing when trying to open some documents. Not all documents, nor is it the same ones every time, nor the oldest or least recently accessed ones. After a reboot, all documents can be opened for another few weeks.
I have also seen the error message from https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/399446/additional-permissions-are-required-to-access-the-following-files at times.
The files' Sharing and Permissions have Read and Write. I tried looking at how many temp files are open or where they are stored but didn't learn anything.

Whatever the root cause of this might be, I found that I can open all documents again for a few weeks by closing all my open documents, then right-clicking the Word icon on the dock and choosing Quit.
